# Thrift IDL Generation

Tags: .net, thrift, thrift-protocol

Is it possible to generate Thrift IDL from C#? Does it even make sense to do so?

I have a REST service, .net45, WebAPI, JSON.  I want to move it to Thrift and I'm looking for shortcuts to create the IDL required as I already have the contract defined in C#.

Comment: Could you show us the contract defined in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course: The IDL is a simple text file.

Regarding the conversion of your existing contract: It depends on how it looks like.